# wires disconnected in back of dryer

Tags: kitchens, appliances

I have an Indesit dryer. I pulled it from wall whilst still plugged in and the wires inside have come loose. I'm not sure which wire connects where.

It is a yellow box labelled `d.e.m f3cc73002v5` inside dryer and there are 3 wires loose: blue, brown, and green/yellow. How should I reconnect them?

Comment: Please post a clearly focused photo of the wall electrical box and the connection point at the back of the dryer. Also state what country or region of the world that you are in. This will enable others to help you with your question.

Comment: A second thing. Please clarify in your question whether this dryer installation is in a home or a business and what type of dryer that it is. Will be very unlikely that people will have any idea what an "indesit" dryer is.

Answer (score 3):

> **a yellow box called d.e.m f3cc73002v5**

That would be an interference suppressor. It has a useful circuit diagram on it which shows how it should be connected. It also shows what it contains (three capacitors and a bleed resistor)

Some images from eBay:
[image]
[image]

L is the live wire in brown insulation
N is the neutral wire in blue insulation
The terminals at the top of the picture are for the earth wire in green/yellow striped insulation.

Note that the middle brown wire has a plastic insulating shroud to keep it apart from the blue wire. That protection is important.

However if all these have been ripped out by force there may be damage that needs repair.

All the connectors on this device are male spade connectors. The wires that connect to them should have female spade connectors crimped onto them. If they have been pulled forcefully off, they are likely to be damaged - check that there are no broken strands.

A damaged wire or connection could start a fire.

A loose wire, could blow a fuse or trip a breaker or electrocute anyone touching the dryer.

The safest thing to do is to get a service engineer to check and fix it.

Comment: May fortune shine upon the humble volunteer electrician. :)